# Twitterizer2 and Twitterizer2.Asynchronous

Tags: c#, .net, twitter, twitterizer

How can i install Twitterizer2 and Twitterizer2.Asynchronous? In the last version of Twitterizer2 i get error like "Unable to parse JSON". Solution of this, to download version from GIT and build it, then add reference.

Without Twitterizer.Asynchronous everything work, but when i try then add Twitterizer2.Asynchronous and use it, i get an error:

> Assembly 'Twitterizer2.Asynchronous, Version=2.4.0.26650,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=69d1469eac671567' uses 'Twitterizer2,
>   Version=2.4.0.26532, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=69d1469eac671567'
>   which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'Twitterizer2,
>   Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=69d1469eac671567'  c:\Users\fs\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\Twtt2\packages\twitterizer-async.2.4.0.26650\lib\net40\Twitterizer2.Asynchronous.dll

Answer (score 1):

Current version of Twitterizer2 2.4.0.26532, and it can't use Twitterizer2.Asynchronous of higher version.

Remove both from references Twitterizer2 and Twitterizer2.Asynchronous, and add both but with compatible version.

To make it easier, try to install them from nuget

http://nuget.org/packages/twitterizer-async

```
Install-Package twitterizer-async -Version 2.4.0.26650
```

Think because Twitterizer2.Asynchronous is depending from Twitterizer2, it installs for you compatible version of Twitterizer2

Comment: Yeah, that's right to unistall NuGet packages and delete reference, but (!!!) don't install from NuGet new packages.

Comment: With NuGet still problem, bcz it reference to Newton.JSON > 4.5, which raise exception of "Unable to parse JSON".

Comment: @user1612334 Ok, see you have found answer. Yeah, in this situation rebuild with appropriate Newtonsoft.Json version - is solution

Answer (score 1):

The solution:

1. Delete all references to twitterizer, twitterizer-async, Newtonsoft.JSON;
2. Go to https://github.com/Twitterizer/Twitterizer and download project;
3. Build Twitterizer2 and Twitterizer2.Async;
4. Add to your project builded in part3 assemblies (dlls);
5. Go to in your project to Package-Manager-Console;
6. Type here: Install-Package Newtonsoft.JSON -version 4.0.5;
7. Profit!

There is still problem with getting twitterizer from NuGet, bcz u have to get an error "Unable to parse JSON",- that's because in NuGet package there is and assembly to Newton.JSON 4.5,- so, you have to add previous version of JSON and before that, build your own assemblies.